# use jQuery to bind a click event to each() of these buttons

Tags: jquery, button, each

I have a bunch of `<button>`s, and they all need somewhere to go when you click them.  I'm sure I can get fancy with jQuery and just make an object with pairs of key/values that designate the class name of the button (key) and the URL where they go when you click them (value).  But I'm having difficulty doing it right.

```
// A lits of button class names and where they go when you click them
var websiteButtons = {
    bmw: "http://www.bmw.com",
    mercedes: "http://www.mercedes.com",
};

// Go through the object, and add behaviors to the buttons
// The key is the button class name, and the value is the URL
// Applied to a click event to go to that URL
$.each(websiteButtons, function(i,e){
    var buttonName = i;
    var buttonLoc = e;
    $('.' + buttonName).on('click', function(){
        window.location = buttonLoc;
    });
});
```

Technically it works, but I feel like I should be doing:

`$.each(websiteButtons, function(buttonName,buttonLoc){...`

instead of:

`$.each(websiteButtons, function(i,e){...`

to save a few lines, but what can I do to make it nice and clean and with best practices? Is there a betterment pattern for this?

Comment: A JSFiddle of the above is [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceninja/9nc7mu4h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It remains the same, both would work

Comment: Ah you're right.  I must have done a typeo when last I tried it, but [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceninja/9nc7mu4h/19/).  But is this the right way to go about it?  Is there a simpler or better way, or is this perfect.

Comment: No this is just perfect, keep that